# treemaps in R: alternatives to the portfolio package?

Tags: r, treemap, portfolio

I would like to generate treemaps in R. Right now I am using the portfolio package, but the problem with this package is that there is not enough ways to control the output: text attributes like font, font size, color can not be controlled, borders between map squares with same color are not distinguishable, there is no control over the color gradient legend etc.

I am looking for a treemap library which allows for a more fine-grained control over the resulting appearance than the portfolio package.

Which alternatives are there to the portfolio package for making treemaps in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to check the treemap package, which I wrote.
Many, if not all of your desired features have been implemented.
If you have any questions or suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To update the above question, there are also interactive treemaps available. Below two packages of possible interest:

```
library("highcharter") on CRAN
library("d3treeR") on Github
```

To learn more about the above packages see the links:
[Highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/shortcuts.html) and [d3treeR](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3treeR)